# How to omit duplicate entries in Google Chrome Javascript Console (in Webdeveloper Tools)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, history

In bash I use

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace
```

to omit duplicate entries be written to bash history. Is it possible to do it in Google Chrome Javascript Console? I often invoke the last command repeatedly to check my latest change effect on my site but then if I want to go back a little I have to press the up key so many times...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be any way to control that. That'd be nice, though... Maybe report it as a feature request for Google Chrome?
Guess for now, your fingers will be getting a lot of exercise... :D